# css modules и использование props для кастомизации компонента

Tags: reactjs

Я создал компонент кнопка, в одном месте мне нужна красная кнопка, в другом серая.

Стили хранятся в css модуле.

**styles.button** это класс в котором прописаны общие стили для всех кнопок, в **styles.buttonClass** я пытаюсь передать нужный класс для кастомизации кнопки, но так это не работает, потому что **buttonClass** воспринимается как имя класса в модуле.

Как правильно сделать, чтобы нужный стиль подключился из css модуля ?

```
import styles from './Button.module.scss'

const Button = ({ children, buttonClass }) => {
  return (
    <button className={`${styles.button} ${styles.buttonClass}`}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Использую компонент

```
<Button buttonClass="grayButton"> Серая кнопка </Button>
<Button buttonClass="redButton"> Красная кнопка </Button>
```

Comment: В вашем `Button.module.scss` какие имена классов для кнопок используются?

Comment: button, grayButton, redButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, это должно работать так:

```
const Button = ({ children, buttonClass }) => {
    return (
        <button className={buttonClass}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}
```

Где **buttonClass** это имя класса, которое будет создано после компиляции вашего **scss** файла в **css**.

Если в **buttonClass** передавать имя из `'./Button.module.scss'`

```
<Button buttonClass="grayButton"> Серая кнопка </Button>
```

то должно выглядеть как то так

```
import styles from './Button.module.scss'

const Button = ({ children, buttonClass }) => {
    return (
        <button className={styles[buttonClass]}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```
import cn from 'classnames';
Import cl from './Button.module.css';

cons Button = ( {className, children} ) => {
return (
      <button className={cn(cl.button, className)}>
           {chilren}
      </button>)}
```