# Почему выдает ошибку в className (React)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
Я по всякому пытаюсь "прикостылить" classChanger к style в className. Но ничего не выходит. Если бы был обычный className, то все сработало бы. Но я с css модулями работаю. А со style я видимо делаю что-то не так. Требуется помощь знатоков :) 

    import styles from "./Card.module.scss";
// импортирую объект styles из соответствующего scss модуля

    const Card = () => {
      const [colorCard, setColorCard] = useState("cardWhite");
      const classChanger = colorCard ? "cardWhite" : "cardGreen";
      const onclickCard = () => setColorCard(!colorCard);
      
    
         
      return (
        <div className={styles.`${classChanger}`} onClick={() => onclickCard()}>
          Card
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Что такое style и styles. ? Что вы хотите получить или сделать? Вам надо изменить класс?

Comment: В `className` записывается строка с перечислением имен классов через пробел. Пример `cls1 cls2`... Что вы хотите получить от styles.`${style}`? Ведь объекта `styles` в примере кода нет...

Comment: исправил. импортирую объект styles из соответствующего scss модуля

Comment: Тогда это styles.`${style}` заменить на это `styles[style]`. Правда еще есть непонятки с вот этим const style = `style.${classChanger}`;

Comment: мне надо, чтобы было так: className = {styles.${classChanger}} . вместого дефолтного класснейма, чтобы был меняющийся по тернарнику при нажатии. Но, так как я написал - не работает. может по другому как надо писать. я пока ответ не нашел

Comment: ksa, спасибо за наводку!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [css modules и использование props для кастомизации компонента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480948/css-modules-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-props-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал так как в коде ниже. Все теперь работает, как я хотел

```
import styles from "./Card.module.scss";

const Card = () => {
  const [colorCard, setColorCard] = useState("cardWhite");
  const classChanger = colorCard ? "cardWhite" : "cardGreen";
  const onclickCard = () => setColorCard(!colorCard);
  console.log(colorCard);

  return (
    <div className={styles[classChanger]} onClick={() => onclickCard()}>
      Card
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```